# Referencing a dynamically created table in SSIS "source assistance"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS project that does the following:
Executes a sql task (in the control flow) that creates (and populates with data) 4 tables.    After that executes I have a Data Flow task that references those 4 tables, joins them, then uses the destination assistant to create a new table called "Step".  Then, those 4 tables are deleted leaving only the "Step" table.

However, when I try to run it it throws an error because technically I am referencing 4 tables that do not yet exist.  How do I work around this?

Comment: first did you try setting DelayValidation to true on the step that errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this the same way you have to [handle temp tables in a data flow source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/65112/).

Use a stored procedure for your datasource, and start it with something like:

```
IF 1=0
 SELECT 
   {dummy-valued column list that matches the column names and datatypes of your expected output}
ELSE
   {your real stored procedure code}
```